# csh variable name must begin with a letter

Tags: macos, terminal, csh

I trying to put a list into a column by using

```
set stats = awk '{if(NR>=1) print $1}' $STATFILE
```

but keep getting the error message "variable name must begin with letter" Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tcsh/csh is expecting no whitespace around the `=` mark.  This would work better:

```
set stats=awk '{if(NR>=1) print $1}' $STATFILE
```

However, it still is not workable, since there is more than one token on the right-side of `=`.  You may have meant something lik

```
set stats=`awk '{if(NR>=1) print $1}' $STATFILE`
```

using backtic ` to get the output of the `awk` command.  Or you could have meant just a string:

```
set stats="awk '{if(NR>=1) print $1}' $STATFILE"
```

Either way, some work is needed.